# How do you determine where a polynomial evaluates to a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

How do you determine where a polynomial evaluates to a perfect square?

One example would be $f(x)=x^2+148x-288$. $f(68) = 14400 = 120^2$.

Another one would be $f(x)=x^2+204x-88$. $f(2) = 324 = 18^2$.

I am looking for a way to find points on a parabola where the function evaluates to a perfect square *without guessing and checking values of x*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first example, we complete the square and get the polynomial $(x+74)^2-5764$. If this is to be the perfect square $z^2$, then we get
$$y^2-z^2=5764,$$
where $y=x+74$.
Express $5764$ is any way as a product of two even integers $u$ and $v$. Set $y-z=u$ and $y+z=v$ and solve for $z$. That will give all solutions.

Since $5764=2^2\cdot 11\cdot 131$, there are not many possibilities for $u$ and $v$. We can have $u=\pm 2$, $v=\pm 2882$ (same sign for each), or $u=\pm 22$, $v=\pm 262$, or the same things with the roles of $u$ and $v$ reversed.

The same method works for your second quadratic, indeed any quadratic of the shape $x^2+2bx+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers. If after completing the square we obtain $y^2-z^2=K$ where $K$ is odd, instead of finding all pairs of even integers $(u,v)$ such that $uv=K$, we use all pairs $(u,v)$ of integers with $uv=K$.

This procedure gives us all solutions. The downside is that factorization can be computationally difficult when the numbers involved are very large.

**Remark:** Things get much more complicated for general $ax^2+bx+c$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers, with $a$ not a perfect square. But one can get useful information using th theory of Pell equations.